# what's wrong with this line of code? Why it isn't passing parameter to update function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Here is my line of code:

```
Response.Write(String.Format("<td id = {0} onclick = 'update({0})' >", studentid));
```

JavaScript function is being called but the parameter is not being passed. What went wrong?
Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked `studentid` value just above that line?

Comment: Add ticks around **id**.

Comment: Here problem is about onclick and function. Not id @user7908029

Comment: Yes. I declared a string value to `studentid`@Xaqron

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that `studentid` is a string. If that's the case, you need to add quotes around it on the `onclick` function.

```
Response.Write(String.Format("<td id = {0} onclick = 'update(\"{0}\")' >", studentid));
```

Why? Because without the quotes, the code will be `onclick='update(student00)'` (where student00 is a student id), and `student00` is a variable, not a string and hence undefined.

Wrapping it in quotes means that onclick is called with a string value. `onclick='update("student00")'`

Comment: could you pls delete the answer or upvote the question?

Comment: That's a weird request...

Comment: I am blocked from asking questions as somene downvoted my questions. So..